# Looping in Spark dataframes using python

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to loop through spark dataframe, check if a condition i.e aggregated value of multiple rows is true/false then create a dataframe. Please see the code outline, can you please help fix the code? i'm pretty new to spark and python- struggling may way through it,any help is greatly appreciated

## sort trades by Instrument  and date (in asc order)

```
dfsorted = df.orderBy('Instrument','Date').show()
```

## new temp variable to keep track of the quantity sum

```
sumofquantity = 0
```

## for each row in the dfsorted

```
sumofquantity = sumofquantity + dfsorted['Quantity']
```

## keep appending the rows looped thus far into this new dataframe called dftemp

```
dftemp= dfsorted (how to write this?)



if ( sumofquantity == 0)
```

## once the sumofquantity becomes zero, for all the rows in the tempview-add a new column with unique seqential number

## and append rows into the final dataframe

```
dffinal= dftemp.withColumn('trade#', assign a unique trade number)
```

## reset the sumofquantity back to 0

```
sumofquantity = 0
```

## clear the dftemp-how to clear the dataframe so i can start wtih zero rows for next iteration?

> trade_sample.csv ( raw input file)

```
Customer ID,Instrument,Action,Date,Price,Quantity 
U16,ADM6,BUY,20160516,0.7337,2
U16,ADM6,SELL,20160516,0.7337,-1
U16,ADM6,SELL,20160516,0.9439,-1
U16,CLM6,BUY,20160516,48.09,1
U16,CLM6,SELL,20160517,48.08,-1
U16,ZSM6,BUY,20160517,48.09,1
U16,ZSM6,SELL,20160518,48.08,-1
```

> Expected Result ( notice last new column-that is all that I'm trying to add)

```
Customer ID,Instrument,Action,Date,Price,Quantity,trade#
U16,ADM6,BUY,20160516,0.7337,2,10001
U16,ADM6,SELL,20160516,0.7337,-1,10001 
U16,ADM6,SELL,20160516,0.9439,-1,10001 
U16,CLM6,BUY,20160516,48.09,1,10002 
U16,CLM6,SELL,20160517,48.08,-1,10002 
U16,ZSM6,BUY,20160517,48.09,1,10003 
U16,ZSM6,SELL,20160518,48.08,-1,10003
```

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output correctly. In inout & Output dataset, one column missing w.r.t. values and also have multiple separator in data (, & ;)

Comment: As per your dataset sum will be always zero for same Customer_ID , Instrument. Is it correct? if yes then we can use trade# as  concatenate of Customer_ID and Instruments like U16ADM6 and after it we can change it as per number 10001. Please let me know if I am wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Looping in such way is not good practice. You can not add/sum dataframe cumulatively and clear immutable dataframe. For your problem you can use spark windowing concept. 
As much I understand your problem you want to calculate sum of `Quantity` for each `customer ID`. Once it complete **sum** for one Customer ID you reset  `sumofquantity` to zero. If it is so, then you can partition `Customer ID` with order by `Instrument` , `Date` and calculate sum for each `Customer ID`. Once you get sum then you can check for `trade#` with your conditions.

just refer below code:

```
    >>> from pyspark.sql.window import Window
    >>> from pyspark.sql.functions import row_number,col,sum
    >>> w = Window.partitionBy("Customer ID").orderBy("Instrument","Date")
    >>> w1 = Window.partitionBy("Customer ID").orderBy("Instrument","Date","rn")
    >>> dftemp =  Df.withColumn("rn", (row_number().over(w))).withColumn("sumofquantity", sum("Quantity").over(w1)).select("Customer_ID","Instrument","Action","Date","Price","Quantity","sumofquantity")
    >>> dftemp.show()
+-----------+----------+------+--------+------+--------+-------------+
|Customer_ID|Instrument|Action|    Date| Price|Quantity|sumofquantity|
+-----------+----------+------+--------+------+--------+-------------+
|        U16|      ADM6|   BUY|20160516|0.7337|       2|            2|
|        U16|      ADM6|  SELL|20160516|0.7337|      -1|            1|
|        U16|      ADM6|  SELL|20160516|0.9439|      -1|            0|
|        U16|      CLM6|   BUY|20160516| 48.09|       1|            1|
|        U16|      CLM6|  SELL|20160517| 48.08|      -1|            0|
|        U16|      ZSM6|   BUY|20160517| 48.09|       1|            1|
|        U16|      ZSM6|  SELL|20160518| 48.08|      -1|            0|
+-----------+----------+------+--------+------+--------+-------------+
```

You can refer Window function at below link:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html
https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html